# C# And MongoDB Create DB from Code

Tags: c#, mongodb, bigdata

Hi Im Trying to create a DataBase in MongoDB from C# code This is the code Im Useing

```
    public partial class SqlToMongo : Form
{
    public SqlToMongo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connectToMongo();
    }
    public void connectToMongo(){
        var con = "mongodb://127.0.0.1";
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(con);
        var db = client.GetDatabase("BetsOdds");
      bool d =  db.RunCommandAsync((Command<BsonDocument>)"{ping:1}")
    .Wait(2000);
        var Betsodds = db.GetCollection<BetOdds>("Betodds");
    }
}
```

The ping return true when MongoService is running and false when the service is off, the code works.
I'm using RoboMongo as a GUI for MongoDB and after the code runs i still don't see the Database on the GUI. i need some help what i'm doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: Have you refreshed the particular connection in RoboMongo. For every change to the database we need to refresh to see the changes in RoboMongo. A bit weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database will not show up in the list until you have added some data.  I have not used RoboMongo, but if you create a database in code, and then using the Mongo console to list the databases, you will not see anything.  Add some data and try again, the database will show up in the list of the 'show dbs' command.